# How do I format an array of array to be POSTed to an API?

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I have an array of arrays that I need to format and sent to an external API. My goal is to take the CoreLocation coordinate data, and send that to an API.

Below is an example:

MBP:www $ xcrun swift -version

Apple Swift version 2.1.1 (swiftlang-700.1.101.15 clang-700.1.81)

Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0

Libraries in use:

- Swiftyjson 1.0
- Alamofire 3.0.1

{

```
t1 = "2015-12-14";
t2 = "6517.8432";
t3 = Miles;
locations = (
    {
        latitude = "37.34229154”;
        longitude = "-122.092223”;
        timestamp = "2015-11-12”;
    },
    {
        latitude = "37.37778312”;
        longitude = "-122.14944148”;
        timestamp = "2015-11-12”;
    },
    {
        latitude = "37.3780272”;
        longitude = "-122.14968145”;
        timestamp = "2015-11-12”;
    },
    {
        latitude = "37.37828075”;
        longitude = "-122.14990349”;
        timestamp = "2015-11-12”;
    },
    {
        latitude = "37.37854172”;
        longitude = "-122.15010976”;
        timestamp = "2015-11-12”;
    }
);
t5 = “Test123";
t6 = "";
t7 = "good";
t8 = “Running";
t9 = "4";
```

}

I use Alamofire to send the data to the API via HTTP POST

### Alamofire.request(.POST, endpoint, headers: headers, parameters: ["data": data])

The request above is converted below. Notice how the location data ('latitude', 'longitude', 'timestamp') are each arrays. My goal is keep the 'latitude', 'longitude', and 'timestamp' contained in an array grouped together.

{

```
“t3" : "Miles",
    “t8" : "Running",
    “t2" : "6517.8432",
    “t7" : "good",
    “t6" : "",
    “t1" : "2015-12-14",
    "locations" : [
        {
            "timestamp" : "2015-11-12"
        },
        {
            "longitude" : "-122.092223"
        },
        {
            "latitude" : "37.34229154"
        },
        {
            "timestamp" : "2015-11-12"
        },
        {
            "longitude" : "-122.14944148"
        },
        {
            "latitude" : "37.37778312"
        },
        {
          "timestamp" : "2015-11-12"
        },
        {
          "longitude" : "-122.14968145"
        },
        {
          "latitude" : "37.3780272"
        },
        {
          "timestamp" : "2015-11-12"
        },
        {
          "longitude" : "-122.14990349"
        },
        {
          "latitude" : "37.37828075"
        },
        {
          "timestamp" : "2015-11-12"
        },
        {
          "longitude" : "-122.15010976"
        },
        {
          "latitude" : "37.37854172"
        }
],
“t9" : "4",
“t5" : "Test123"
```

}

Comment: What type is "locations"? I have never seen this Swift syntax you are using to define "locations". Why do you use: ( { ... ; ... ; .... ;} ) This not how arrays are created in Swift.

Comment: @Darko The locations is my attempt to create an array of arrays. The ouster array should contain the location arrays, and the inner array should contain the location data (latitude, longitude, timestamp). What is the correct way to format this? Thanks for your replay!

Answer (score 0):

Use square brackets for both inner and outer arrays.